# Crashlytics don’t send crash report when there is another crash report (Umeng)

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I’ve implemented Crashlytics (2.2.4) in my iOS app for crash report collection. I also implemented another third-party component (Umeng) for other data collection. However, Crashlytics doesn’t send report when Umeng is turned on.  When I check the log, there are these suspicious warnings:

```
[Crashlytics] Warning: NSUncaughtExceptionHandler is 'UmengHandleException'  
[Crashlytics] Warning: sigabrt handler is ‘UmengSignalHandler'  
[Crashlytics] Warning: sigbus handler is 'UmengSignalHandler' 
[Crashlytics] Warning: sigfpe handler is 'UmengSignalHandler' 
[Crashlytics] Warning: sigill handler is 'UmengSignalHandler' 
[Crashlytics] Warning: sigsegv handler is ‘UmengSignalHandler'
```

When Umeng is turned off, these warnings are gone and the reports are well sent.

I have put Crashlytics last to call in AppDelegate, but the warning is still there. 
Is there a way to work around this issue so that Crashlytics can send report when Umeng is turned on?

Comment: I also had this kind of problem. But it won't be of any help since you said that you put the crashlytics call the last. However, it worked for me. The other SDK that I was using was testflight.

This is also the suggestion in the crashlytics FAQ.

http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92506-are-you-compatible-with-other-sdks

Comment: Hi, @RaymondBrion, this FAQ suggestion is the reason I tried to put the line in the last. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. There is also another link seems to be related, but I don't know how to implement in my case: Can I use a custom Exception Handler? [link](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/222764-can-i-use-a-custom-exception-handler)

Answer (score 3):

Self answer. 
I got an advice from another developer on Umeng's support forum, which is to put the set report disable method before the startWithKey method. The trick is to use this method BEFORE not after the startWithKey. I am trapped by this pitfalll for two days.

```
[MobClick setCrashReportEnabled:NO];
[MobClick startWithAppkey:YOURKEY reportPolicy:YOURPOLICY channelId:YOURCHANNELID];
```

Comment: Have you met one problem that if you turn on crashlytics debug mode, right after you trigger a crash, then hook up Xcode, the terminal is saying 'no files to submit'.  check my problem with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521962/crashlytics-dont-detect-crash-file-to-submit?noredirect=1#comment45360660_28521962

Comment: I solved my issue by your answer, seems Umeng SDK really blocked exceptions for further handling.