# crashlytics don't detect crash file to submit, affected by Umeng SDK

Tags: ios

I setup crashlytics and turning on debug mode,

I tried `[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];`
it will have files to submit;

I tried `int *x = NULL; *x = 42;`
it will have files to submit;

But I tried

```
NSArray *a = @[@1,@2];
[a objectAtIndex:5];
```

it will not have files to submit. What is the condition for crashlytics to generate files to submit? I am confused it seems not every crash it will report.

The `[a objectAtIndex:5];` log:

```
2015-02-13 13:34:11.344 Compass[1589:277586] [Crashlytics] Settings loaded
2015-02-13 13:34:11.351 Compass[1589:277586] [Crashlytics] Configuring application
2015-02-13 13:34:11.352 Compass[1589:277586] [Crashlytics] Starting report processing in 1.0 second(s)...
2015-02-13 13:34:12.451 Compass[1589:277587] [Crashlytics] Alternate file submission complete
2015-02-13 13:34:12.453 Compass[1589:277587] [Crashlytics] No prepared files found
2015-02-13 13:34:12.454 Compass[1589:277587] [Crashlytics] No sendable files, submission process complete
2015-02-13 13:34:13.272 Compass[1589:277585] [Crashlytics] Configured application
```

compared to [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]:

```
2015-02-13 15:36:11.716 Compass[1634:288568] [Crashlytics] Processed file successfully
2015-02-13 15:36:11.717 Compass[1634:288568] [Crashlytics] Alternate file submission complete
2015-02-13 15:36:11.718 Compass[1634:288568] [Crashlytics] Submitting files
2015-02-13 15:36:13.750 Compass[1634:288561] [Crashlytics] Submission response: {status: 202, error: (null)}
2015-02-13 15:36:13.751 Compass[1634:288561] [Crashlytics] Submitted crash report with file name: "54dda95f01cf0001065d333333376237.cls", request-id: <none received>
2015-02-13 15:36:13.752 Compass[1634:288569] [Crashlytics] Submitted file successfully
2015-02-13 15:36:13.754 Compass[1634:288569] [Crashlytics] No sendable files, submission process complete
```

Comment: Try again without attaching Xcode. i.e. start the app from the device or the iOS simulator. Don't use the Run button in Xcode

Comment: No it is not your case. I did all experiment without Xcode hooked when crashing. I just reconnect to Xcode after crash, and checking how crashlytics behaves. if it is saying submitting files, then I will get the report. If there is no files to send even right after the crash, no report on website.

Comment: i am truly confused, crashlytics not detecting every crash, just some of them, I am not sure what did i do. I tried clean up my project and start over setting up crashlytics over and over, but no luck. Crashlytics seems working, but ignoring crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self answer:

It turned out to be that another SDK called Umeng also has a crash reporting feature, and it silently handled all exceptions, so I suppose crashlytics cannot get the exception.

I did disabled Umeng SDK crash reporting, but the true magic is:

```
[MobClick setCrashReportEnabled:NO];
[MobClick startWithAppkey:@"Your Key"];
```

`[MobClick setCrashReportEnabled:NO];` must put before `startWithAppkey:`, otherwise it is already set.

I am delighted by [Crashlytics don’t send crash report when there is another crash report (Umeng)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090629/crashlytics-don-t-send-crash-report-when-there-is-another-crash-report-umeng/26111326#comment45362209_26111326)